# How to autostart python GUI application on ubuntu boot?

Tags: gnome, python, autostart

I've tried rc-local method, creating a `.desktop` script, ubuntu autostart application but none of them worked. Below is the content of the `.desktop` script file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=MyScript
Comment=MyScript
Icon=gnome-info
Exec=python3 /home/unity/Desktop/VISIONNUC/test_2.py
Terminal=False
Type=Application
Categories=

X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To auto start application, place its binary path in `gnome-session-properties`:

Run in terminal:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Add new item to the list specifying its Name and Command as it is for existent items.

In your case it would look like:

[image]

Use `whereis python3` to find out your full path to `python3` binary.

But it would be executed not at boot but at your user's log in.

Comment: I've disabled login for the root user.
in fact, I tried this method earlier but I guess I was doing it wrong. I didn't provide the path to the python 3.6.
earlier I was doing : python3/home/unity/Desktop/VISIONNUC/test_2.py

Comment: Thank you so much I completed all of my project R&D and testing just stuck at this from the last 4 days. anyway, thanks a million.

Comment: I did that buddy. Thanks a million.

Comment: Glad to hear) no problems)